# VBA excel - copy row content below

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the whole contents of a row into the next row, when it meets some criteria. So if I'm in row 3 i want that row 4 would have the exact contents of row 3.

The problem is that row 4 already has a content of its own. How can i shift it down and then copy my desired contents?

I have only tried the `Entirerow.Copy` and paste special method but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial
```

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Macro - Copy and insert copied cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455635/excel-vba-macro-copy-and-insert-copied-cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the code below:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    .Rows(Range("A2").Row).Copy
    .Range("A3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you!