# VBA Copy a range of cells and paste them after a certain offset

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a range of cells and pasting them in the same worksheet but a few columns away. I am getting an application defined error. What gives? I followed this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455635/excel-vba-macro-copy-and-insert-copied-cells):

```
    MsgBox "Would you like to save the chart data for the completed sprint?", vbOKCancel
    If answer = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Copying ..."

        Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AN:AY").Copy
        Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AN:AY").Offset(3).Insert Shift:=xlRight
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Else
        End
    End If
```

***UPDATE***

After modifying offset(3) to offset(0,3), I have encountered a new error that's not completely display (what the heck Excel?)

[image]

Comment: You could have looked it up in Help or googled. `Offset` is rows, columns so you need `offset(0,3)` or if you're lazy like me `offset(,3)`.

Comment: `xlShiftToRight` as well... but I think there's still a problem.

Comment: Yeap, there is still a problem, yessir.

Comment: Where do you want the columns to be inserted - after `AP`?

Comment: @SJR - thank you for your reply. Excel just spat an ugly message at my face. See my question for screen-grabs.

Comment: Try doing this manually. Do you get an error? I'm not sure where exactly you're trying to insert the columns.

Comment: I am able to cut/paste them manually just fine. I need to make space for new set of data.

Comment: Cut/paste is not the same as *insert copied cells*. The macro recorder is helpful here.

Comment: Never used a macro recorder. Sorry! VBA programming is completely new to me.I have always used Excel for trivial uses before now :(

Comment: AN to AY are more than three columns so you would be inserting this into the middle of the range you are copying.

Comment: *Developer* tab > *Record Macro* :-)

Comment: If you want it 3 columns from where the range ends then you need to use `Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AY:AY").Offset(,3).Insert Shift:=xlRight`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Did you mean to say Range ("AN:AY")?

Comment: @BigBen - So, I clicked on Record Macro option and it said it will save it in "This Workbook". I cut and pasted the range and stopped recording. I went into "This Workbook" to look for code but in vain.

Comment: @Jrules80 no I meant exactly what I typed.

Comment: Haha, yessir. You did. Let me check it out.

Comment: Now if you want the Range to be variable then we can do something like: `Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AN:AY").Offset(,3 + Worksheets("KPIs").Range("AN:AY").columns.Count).Insert Shift:=xlRight` then you can just use the size of the range and add 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! That worked. Cannot thank this forum enough and to all you guys that pitch in to help.You guys have no idea how grateful I am :) Keep it up, y'all.